# Logging command line arguements into log4j

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, log4j, linux-kernel

Inside my java code, I have created scenarios where certain shell commands are executed, infact specifically the `-scp-` and `-mv-` commands are executed.
Is it possible to log the results of the execution? For example, if the file to be copied is not found or if the `-scp-` or `-mv-` does not occur properly it logs to the logfile I have prepared. Currently my command execution code is as follows:

```
  if ("command") {
                String command = "mv " + source_file_path + "/"
                        + " " + dest_file_path;
                Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                exitVal = child.waitFor();

                // Get the input stream and read from it
                InputStream in = child.getInputStream();

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c = bis.read();

                while (c != -1) {
                    byte b = (byte) c;
                    buf.write(b);
                    c = bis.read();
                }
                in.close();
                System.out.println("Input Stream: " + buf.toString());
                buf.close();
                bis.close();
                InputStream ein = child.getErrorStream();
                BufferedInputStream ebis = new BufferedInputStream(ein);
                ByteArrayOutputStream ebuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int ce = ebis.read();

                while (ce != -1) {
                    // process((char)c);
                    byte be = (byte) ce;
                    ebuf.write(be);
                    ce = ebis.read();
                }
                ein.close();
                System.out.println("Error Stream: " + ebuf.toString());
                ebuf.close();
                ebis.close();   
        }   
        System.exit(0);
```

Is there anyway I can add a logging component on it? To log for when file is not found, when file did not transfer properly, when file transfered has a problem..etc

Comment: Are you just wanting to log the output of the command or are you wanting to parse the output of the command and log particular messages depending on the case?

Comment: I want to log particular messages dependingon the case.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the output of the command, which you're capturing in the ByteArrayOutputStream called `buf` to determine the result, and log it. You might also get a clue from the [exit code of the process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29), which you stored in `exitVal`.

Note that by calling child.waitFor() before reading the stdout and stderr streams, you're guaranteeing that this won't work if the output of the process gets too large. Per the [Process API docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html): "Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock."

Comment: So what do you suggest? How should I handle it?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Handle what?